# Параллельные запросы к MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Подскажите решение:
Есть 5 mysql серверов
Есть программа написана на php
В базе данных храниться список товаров, шардированы по коду, бывает такое что товары одного кода разнесены на несколько серверов, и если нужно достать весь список товара определенного кода, нужно делать несколько запросов к серверам по очереди, это очень не удобно.

Подскажите решение параллельного выполнение запросов к серверам?

Comment: Вы сами себе противоречите. Пишите, что данные "шардированы по коду" и тут же пишите "товары одного кода разнесены на несколько серверов". Это две взаимоисключающие фразы. Если код товара выбран как ключ шардирования по нему должно быть однозначное определение хранящего сервера. Приведите в порядок вашу БД, разложив данные по серверам на основе кода. Или найдите другой ключ

Comment: Сории чуть не так написал, есть код (к примеру клиента), у этого кода может быть 100-1000 товаров, шардирование по коду товара. Суть вопроса все равно открыта,тут не имеет значение впорядке база или нет. Суть как сделать параллельные запросы на несколько серверов.

Comment: Судя по всему в mysqli (и только в нем) есть поддержка асинхронных запросов https://habrahabr.ru/post/155377/  И вам в любом случае нужно что то из этой оперы. Если подходящих асинхронных функций для БД все таки не найдется, то видимо придется делать некий отвечающий API на стороне шардинга, который будет общаться на сокетах и организовывать в вызывающем приложении асинхронную работу с сокетами (в части отправки запросов на API). Или смотреть в сторону многопоточных приложений (при этом слой API скорее всего так же понадобится)

Comment: Я думал написать программку на GO ей передаю sql запрос, она идет на сервера и возвращает данные

Comment: ну да, использование языка из коробки поддерживающего асинхронность явно правильное направление (я же правильно понимаю что в go это само собой разумеется ?). (Это и будет тот самый API о котором я говорил). Правда SQL запрос как то уже не совсем правильно, лучше все таки какой нибудь простенький API сделать, хоть на том же json

Comment: Понял, буду так и делать. Спасибо.